# Static variables in another file in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently having trouble modifying a static variable in another file in Python.

**FileA**

```
class MainClass(object):
    global_var = 0
    def __init__(self):
        MainClass.global_var = 1

class SecondClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        MainClass.global_var = 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = MainClass()
    print "After MainClass:" + str(MainClass.global_var)

    second = SecondClass()
    print "After SecondClass:" + str(MainClass.global_var)

    from FileB import ThirdClass
    third = ThirdClass()
    print "After ThirdClass:" + str(MainClass.global_var)
```

**FileB**

```
class ThirdClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        from FileA import MainClass
        MainClass.global_var = 3
```

**Output**

```
After MainClass:1
After SecondClass:2
After ThirdClass:2
```

I would like to modify the static variable in MainClass to 3 in FileB. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible. It is weird to import one file that import the other file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got two separate instances of the MainClass class! This is due to the way Python imports work.

You can verify this by printing `id(MainClass)` from `FileA` and also after you've imported it in the `__init__` in `FileB`

This isn't a bug in Python, you're just trying to do something that the Python language does not specify should work.

Experimenting with code like this is good for learning, but I hope you're not trying to do something like this is a real program. There is certainly a better way than spaghetti<sup>†</sup> code like this.

† Apologies to any spaghetti that was offended by this comment.

Comment: This means that you can not do this? It won't never change the value of the variable?

Comment: @DaviSampaio, It changes the value, but there are two classes called MainClass. Changes in one won't affect the other

Comment: So @WLin how did you do to change the value?

Comment: @DaviSampaio, I changed the implementation. I'm now passing an instance of MainClass and modifying the instance's values instead.

Comment: I also wanted to add that this issue can also be fixed by using the same base module (eg. from file.FileA and file.FileB).